# Checking for existence in std::map - count vs find

Tags: c++, dictionary, stl, stdmap

So there seem to be two generally acceptable methods of determining whether or not a key exists in a `std::map`:

```
map.find(key) != map.end()
map.count(key) > 0
```

Is one more efficient than the other? Specifically, the concept of `count()` could be interpreted to mean that the method will iterate over every key, tallying a total count (and because of the definition of `std::map`, that total count will always be 0 or 1). Is `count()` guaranteed to "stop" after a match, operating at the same complexity as a `find()`?

Comment: `count` can only be `0` or `1` for an `std::map`. The complexity is the same. Note that you don't need the `> 0` comparison.

Comment: the return of count can only be 0 or 1 (for std::map), but that is not the same as saying that the underlying implementation will guarantee that this is done efficiently

Comment: The logarithmic complexity is a good indicator that the implementation is efficient.

Answer (score 79, accepted):

Since a map can only have at most one key, `count` will essentially stop after one element has been found. However, in view of more general containers such as multimaps and multisets, `find` is strictly better if you only care whether *some* element with this key exists, since it can really stop once the first matching element has been found.

In general, both `count` and `find` will use the container-specific lookup methods (tree traversal or hash table lookup), which are always fairly efficient. It's just that `count` has to continue iterating until the end of the equal-range, whereas `find` does not. Moreover, your code should document intent, so if you want to find something, use `find`.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, although I want to be clear on your first sentence. Is it that count *should* stop after one element has been found, or that count *will* stop after one element has been found? In other words, is it guaranteed for std::map?

Comment: @dolphy: As I tried to say, the map uses its internal data structure for the lookup, so for a given key it will efficiently find the range of all elements with that key (e.g. binary search in a tree), and for `count` it will return the length of that range.

Comment: Now, in the C++20, you can use `std::map::contains` to check is key is present in the map.

Answer (score 20):

According to the source code, I suggest to use `find`. See the source code.

In GCC, the code is following (`stl_map.h`):

```
    const_iterator
    find(const key_type& __x) const
    { return _M_t.find(__x); }

    size_type                                                                              
    count(const key_type& __x) const                                                       
    { return _M_t.find(__x) == _M_t.end() ? 0 : 1; }
```

In Visual Studio on the windows platform, the code are following (`xtree`):

```
    const_iterator find(const key_type& _Keyval) const
    {   // find an element in nonmutable sequence that matches _Keyval
        const_iterator _Where = lower_bound(_Keyval);
        return (_Where == end()
            || _DEBUG_LT_PRED(this->_Getcomp(),
                _Keyval, this->_Key(_Where._Mynode()))
                    ? end() : _Where);
    }

    //....

    const_iterator lower_bound(const key_type& _Keyval) const
    {   // find leftmost node not less than _Keyval in nonmutable tree
        return (const_iterator(_Lbound(_Keyval), this));
    }

    //....

    _Nodeptr _Lbound(const key_type& _Keyval) const
    {   // find leftmost node not less than _Keyval
        _Nodeptr _Pnode = _Root();
        _Nodeptr _Wherenode = this->_Myhead;    // end() if search fails

        while (!this->_Isnil(_Pnode))
            if (_DEBUG_LT_PRED(this->_Getcomp(), this->_Key(_Pnode), _Keyval))
                _Pnode = this->_Right(_Pnode);  // descend right subtree
            else
                {   // _Pnode not less than _Keyval, remember it
                _Wherenode = _Pnode;
                _Pnode = this->_Left(_Pnode);   // descend left subtree
                }

        return (_Wherenode);    // return best remembered candidate
    }

    //..........................................
    //..........................................

    size_type count(const key_type& _Keyval) const
    {   // count all elements that match _Keyval
        _Paircc _Ans = equal_range(_Keyval);
        size_type _Num = 0;
        _Distance(_Ans.first, _Ans.second, _Num);
        return (_Num);
    }

    //....

    _Pairii equal_range(const key_type& _Keyval) const
    {   // find range equivalent to _Keyval in nonmutable tree
        return (_Eqrange(_Keyval));
    }

    //....

    _Paircc _Eqrange(const key_type& _Keyval) const
    {   // find leftmost node not less than _Keyval
        _Nodeptr _Pnode = _Root();
        _Nodeptr _Lonode = this->_Myhead;   // end() if search fails
        _Nodeptr _Hinode = this->_Myhead;   // end() if search fails

        while (!this->_Isnil(_Pnode))
            if (_DEBUG_LT_PRED(this->_Getcomp(), this->_Key(_Pnode), _Keyval))
                _Pnode = this->_Right(_Pnode);  // descend right subtree
            else
                {   // _Pnode not less than _Keyval, remember it
                if (this->_Isnil(_Hinode)
                        && _DEBUG_LT_PRED(this->_Getcomp(), _Keyval,
                        this->_Key(_Pnode)))
                    _Hinode = _Pnode;   // _Pnode greater, remember it
                _Lonode = _Pnode;
                _Pnode = this->_Left(_Pnode);   // descend left subtree
                }

        _Pnode = this->_Isnil(_Hinode) ? _Root()
            : this->_Left(_Hinode); // continue scan for upper bound
        while (!this->_Isnil(_Pnode))
            if (_DEBUG_LT_PRED(this->_Getcomp(), _Keyval, this->_Key(_Pnode)))
                {   // _Pnode greater than _Keyval, remember it
                _Hinode = _Pnode;
                _Pnode = this->_Left(_Pnode);   // descend left subtree
                }
            else
                _Pnode = this->_Right(_Pnode);  // descend right subtree

        const_iterator _First = const_iterator(_Lonode, this);
        const_iterator _Last = const_iterator(_Hinode, this);
        return (_Paircc(_First, _Last));
    }
```

Comment: What is the argument to use find? The GCC example shows that count is implemented in terms of find, so why should I prefer find in that case?

Answer (score 9):

If you just want to find whether the key exists or not, and don't care about the value, it is better to use `map::count` as it returns only an integer. `map::find` returns an iterator, thus by using `count`, you will save the construction of an iterator.

Comment: As you can see in source code (another answer) - implementation of "count" constructs more iterators internally comparing to implementation of "find".

Comment: @Ezh In that answer (I guess you mean Bright Chen's), for GCC the iterators used are the same, not more. According to the code, `if(m.count(i))` does the same as `if(m.find(i) != m.end())`.